# Giving money to friends in GTA 5 online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I know everyone says you can't give cash right now but this morning (17 DEC 2013) a random player gave me $114,000,000 for no reason. I messaged him and thanked him and asked how he did it but he did not respond. so I don't know how its done but I know you can. Anyone know how to do it other than splitting job money?

Comment: I do receive a huge amount of money from a Lv306 player as well. Suspected he is a hacker though.